# How can i Redirect Laravel 7 Bulk Old URL to New URL ? 4000+ Old URLs to New

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8, laravel-7, laravel-6

I want to redirect my Old URL to New URL

OLD URL : http://example.com/productsite-reviews

New URL : http://example.com/reviews/productsite.com

The problem is i have more than 4000+ URLS. Can we redirect the old URL to New URL without .htaccess file ?

this is my home route

`Route::get('/', 'HomeController')->name( 'home' );`

Is there any way to redirect these URL in bulk without writing htaccess code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, redirect it to new controller using

```
Route::get('/', function () {
 return redirect('/reviews/productsite.com');
  });
```

And then change the current route to

```
Route::get('/reviews/productsite.com', 'HomeController')->name( 'home' );
```